# Как сделать переключение классов в обратном порядке?

Tags: javascript

```js
let button = document.querySelector('.btn'),
  blocks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block')),
  pointer = 0;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Убираем прошлый блок
  blocks[pointer].classList.remove('active');

  if (pointer + 1 >= blocks.length)
    pointer = 0;
  else
    pointer++;


  // Отмечаем новый блок
  blocks[pointer].classList.add('active');
});
```

```css
.main{
 width: 100%;
 height: 800px;
 background-color: grey;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.block{
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 display: none;
 margin: 100px auto;
}
.red{
 background-color: red;
}
.black{
 background-color: black;
}
.green{
 background-color: green;
}
.active{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">button</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block red active"></div>
  <div class="block black"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wb5yn1pu/

Comment: Если у вас сейчас `pointer = 0` и увеличивается, то для обратного порядка надо `pointer = length - 1` и уменьшать, или нет?

Comment: Не получается..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(pointer == 0)
    pointer = blocks.length - 1;
  else
    pointer--;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо